# how to style a dropzone?

Tags: css, vue.js

I would like to know how can I style my dropzone in a circle box? Because my image isn't fit nicely in my div box and the styling is a mess. I am not sure which css is wrong right now

CSS

```
.dropzone{
   border-radius:100%;
    width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   min-height: 0px !important;
  }   

    
  .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-image > img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
  }

  .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-image {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: none;
  }
  
 
  

  .dropzone .dz-default.dz-message  {
       display: none;
   }
```

```
 <b-row class="mb-3">
                                 <b-col cols=12 > 
                                     <label for="input-live">My Information</label>
                                     <b-button  variant="light" style="float:right; background:white; border:none;" @click="deleteBabyInfo(form.id)">Delete</b-button>
                                     <div class="image-container">
                                        <vue-dropzone ref="myVueDropzone" class="dropzone" id="dropzone" @vdropzone-success="UploadCallback" @vdropzone-removed-file="removedCallback" v-on:vdropzone-sending="sendingEvent" :options="dropzoneOptions" ></vue-dropzone>
                                     </div>                             
                                 </b-col>
                                 <b-col cols="5" style="position:absolute; top:70px; left: 160px;"><span>Upload Your Image</span></b-col>
                             </b-row>
```

script

```
export default {
   components: {
       vueDropzone: vue2Dropzone
   },
   data: () => ({
       param: {
       id: null,
   },
   dropzoneOptions: {
       dictDefaultMessage: "",
       url: '/api/profile/upload_img',
       acceptedFiles:'image/*',
       maxFiles: 1,
       thumbnailWidth: 500,
       addRemoveLinks: true,
       dictRemoveFile: 'Delete',
       thumbnailMethod: 'contain',
       maxFilesize: 60,
       resizeMimeType: 'image/jpeg',
       resizeQuality: 0.6,
       resizeWidth:1024,
       headers: { "Document-Type": "my_img" },
   },
```

Below are the output image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use  "*dictDefaultMessage*" option to do custom style in drop area. Example output you can see from here https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwZ8U.png

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
            url: 'upload.php',
            dictDefaultMessage: `<img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/730/348/png-transparent-computer-icons-upload-icon-upload-miscellaneous-angle-rectangle-thumbnail.png"><br><br> Click or drop files here to upload`,
}
```